# How similar are boost::filesystem and std::filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-filesystem, std-filesystem

I believe [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) was at least one of the "source" libraries used to design [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) for C++17.

How similar are they?  If very similar, what are the known gotchas and incompatibilities?  If not, where are they similar?

This is in the context of implementing something with `std::filesystem`, `std::experimental::filesystem` or `boost::filesystem`, and wanting to know the likely scope of efforts required if we switch libraries (say, if one discovers that the `std` library on a particular platform is inadequate).

This is not a request for an alternative library recommendation.

Comment: Hat tip for diverting traffic to my question :-)

Comment: @ein my google fu failed me pretty bad.